# Guava EventBus: pause event posting

Tags: guava

Is there any way to pause event posting by the EventBus from the guava library.

I have a method `changeSomething()` that posts an event (e.g. `SomethingChangedEvent`). Now this method is called in a loop by another method `doStuff()`.
The problem is that the `SomethingChangedEvent` is posted on every call to `changeSomething()` even though only the last change matters. Due to the fact that the handlers of the event execute some heavy-weight calculations, the performance of the application degrades fast.

After the last time `changeSomething()` is executed I would like to tell guava to resume event processing.

Is there any way to tell guava to ignore all `SomethingChangedEvent`s except the very last one?

Comment: How could guava know that it is the very last one ? You need to add a discriminator to your events and filter this manually on the subscriber side.

Comment: @Pache I was thinking of something similar to `eventBus.stopPosting(SomethingChangedEvent.class)` and then right before the last call `eventBus.resumePosting(SomethingChangedEvent.class)`. Changing the event is not option because it is not in my code.

Comment: You could create an event extending `SomethingChangedEvent` like `IgnoreSomethingChangedEvent` and post it to the eventBus. This event will be received by the same publisher that can then set an internal state to ignore, based of a `instanceof IgnoreSomethingChangedEvent`. Create an other event to reactivate it. It is complicated but seems to be the only way (tested and works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this pattern, derived from the poison pill pattern using sub-classing :

```
 public class SomethingChangedEvent {

        private final String name;

        public SomethingChangedEvent(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

    }

    public class IgnoreSomethingChangedEvent extends SomethingChangedEvent {
        public IgnoreSomethingChangedEvent(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

    }

    public class HandleSomethingChangedEvent extends SomethingChangedEvent {
        public HandleSomethingChangedEvent(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

    }

    private void eventBusTest() {
        EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
        eventBus.register(new EventBusSomethingChanged());
        eventBus.post(new SomethingChangedEvent("process this one"));
        eventBus.post(new IgnoreSomethingChangedEvent("ignore"));
        eventBus.post(new SomethingChangedEvent("don't process this one"));
        eventBus.post(new HandleSomethingChangedEvent("handle"));
        eventBus.post(new SomethingChangedEvent("process this one bis"));
    }

    public class EventBusSomethingChanged {
        private boolean ignore;

        @Subscribe
        public void SomethingChanged(SomethingChangedEvent e) {
            if (e instanceof IgnoreSomethingChangedEvent) {
                ignore = true;
                return;
            }
            if (e instanceof HandleSomethingChangedEvent) {
                ignore = false;
                return;
            }
            if (!ignore) {
                System.out.println("processing:" + e);
            }
        }
    }
```